# The string quote not full,''' has syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update

I execute a update statement in SQL Server 2008:

```
declare @DynamicSQL nvarchar(500)
set @ecaKey='b3 ff c7 ff b9 ff 93 ff bb ff a5 ff a8 ff 86 ff 94 ff 87 ff a6 ff 9a ff 98 ff d4 ff 90 ff ad ff 8c ff 95 ff cb ff a9 ff 91 ff 9b ff 8f ff b1 ff ac ff c6 ff 92 ff 86 ff af ff b6 ff 87 ff 85 ff 91 ff 90 ff ca ff 88 ff 8b ff cc ff 9d ff b2 ff a7 ff bb ff 9c ff c8 ff cf ff 92 ff 8c ff 87 ff 8c ff bb ff ba ff 8f ff ba ff'
set @DynamicSQL='update '+@sysDBName+'..sys_ecasoftkey set softkey=N'''+@ecaKey+''' where state=''1'''
exec(@DynamicSQL)
```

It tips that:

```
Message 105，Level 15，state 1， 1 row
The string 'b3 ff c7 ff b9 ff 93 ff bb ff a5 ff a8 ff 86 ff 94 ff 87 ff a6 ff 9a ff 98 ff d4 ff 90 ff ad ff 8c ff 95 ff cb ff a9 ff 91 ff 9b ff 8f ff b1 ff ac ff c6 ff 92 ff 86 ff af ff b6 ff 87 ff 85 ff 91 ff 90 ff ca ff 88 ff 8b ff cc ff 9d ff b2 ff a7 ff bb ff 9c ff c8 ff cf ff 92 ff 8c ff 87 ff 8c ff bb ff ba ff 8f ff ba ff bc ff d4 ff 8b ff b6 ff ba ff bd ff 97 ff a6 ff 98 ff 95 ff 9d ff ab ff aa ff ba ff a5 ff cd ff 9d ff 94 ff c7 ff ba ff bc ff b0 ff 9b' don't have full quote。
Message 102，level 15，state 1， 1 row
'b3 ff c7 ff b9 ff 93 ff bb ff a5 ff a8 ff 86 ff 94 ff 87 ff a6 ff 9a ff 98 ff d4 ff 90 ff ad ff 8c ff 95 ff cb ff a9 ff 91 ff 9b ' nearby has syntax error.
```

The softkey and state columns is `varchar`.

Where is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's because the length of `@DynamicSQL` is not long enough.Change your length like this:

```
declare @DynamicSQL nvarchar(2000)
```

Although your current string(500) is long enough, but this problem is cause by this reason exactly.

When i changed the problem resolved.